# `pointer-events: none` attribute applied with Styled Components vs. Vanilla CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

```
//Main.js

<SpanStyle className="texting-container">
  <div className>Click Me</div>
</SpanStyle>
```

The component SpanStyle uses class tag "texting-container" to set the CSS attribute:

```
// sample.css

.texting-container {
    pointer-events: none;
    margin: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
}
```

As of now ,setting `pointer-events: none` is the only way I can set my text tag to be able to "click through" the button it is nested within

The problem is, I'm using Styled Components in my project and instead of using the CSS method like I mentioned, I tried setting the same CSS attribute within the styled component definition, however it doesn't work at all (unlike the former method). Here is the styled component, hopefully somebody can direct me to why it isn't working as intended:

```
//Main.js

const SpanStyle = styled.span`
  position: absolute;
  top: 49%;
  left: 37%;
  transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)"
  pointer-events: none
  cursor: none;
  `;
```

Comment: You have not terminated all the css properties with semicolon